# Многоуровневое условие aiogram_python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram, aiogram-3.x

Помогите пожалуйста, мне надо чтобы если юзер выбираете "Москва" тогда переход на состояние "rayon", а если выбирает "Другое" тогда переход на состояние "adress".
Пока код у меня такой, но условие  не работает

```
@router.message(Reg.region)
async def reg_twelve(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if message.text not in ["Москва","Другое"]:
        await message.answer("Выбрать из кнопок:", reply_markup=kb.region)
    else:
        await state.update_data(region=message.text)
        if message.text == "Москва":
            await state.set_state(Reg.rayon)
        elif message.text == "Другое":
            await state.set_state(Reg.adress)
        await message.answer("Выбрать из кнопок:", reply_markup=kb.rayon)        

@router.message(Reg.rayon)
async def reg_threeteen(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(rayon=message.text)
    await state.set_state(Reg.adress)
    await message.answer("Выбрать из кнопок:",reply_markup=kb.otmena) 

@router.message(Reg.adress)
async def reg_threeteen(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await state.update_data(adress=message.text)
    await state.set_state(Reg.languages)
    await message.answer("Выбрать из кнопок:",reply_markup=kb.otmena)
```

Comment: Что значит не работает? У вас все написано правильно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
@router.message(Reg.region)
async def reg_twelve(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    if message.text.lower() not in ["москва","другое"]:
        await message.answer("Выбрать из кнопок:", reply_markup=kb.region)
    else:
        await state.update_data(region=message.text)
        if message.text.lower() == "москва":
            await state.set_state(Reg.rayon)
        elif message.text.lower() == "другое":
            await state.set_state(Reg.adress)
        await message.answer("Выбрать из кнопок:", reply_markup=kb.rayon)
```

попробуй использовать

```py
.lower()
```

которая сделает все слово в нижний регистр. Возможно поэтому условие не сработало.

p.s. Не тестил. Напиши если не будет работать, помогу ещё

Comment: Зачем писать такие ответы? Ваши догадки или домыслы можно написать в комментарии

Comment: @ClarkDevlin, почему бы и нет?